# Change password is firing when the enter key is hit in any textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a searchbar on my site, but the problem is that when the user is in their profile I display a changepassword asp.net object. I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

```
<asp:ChangePassword ID="ChangePassword1" runat="server" SuccessTextStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" CancelButtonText="" CancelButtonType="Link" ContinueButtonText="" ContinueButtonType="Link">
</asp:ChangePassword>
```

When I try to add my searchbar

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch123" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtSearch123_TextChanged" Width="217px" Text="Search for an item..." OnClick="this.value=''" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>
```

When the user presses enter, the search never completes because the textboxes inside in the change password are empty and they light up as if the user is trying to change their password. Even though they aren't linked what so ever.

Any ideas?

Following Works:

`<asp:ChangePassword ID="ChangePassword2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Password"> </asp:ChangePassword>`

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch123" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtSearch123_TextChanged" Width="155px" Text="Search for an item..." OnClick="this.value=''" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" ValidationGroup="SearchItem"></asp:TextBox>`

`<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="" Width="0" Height="0" ValidationGroup="SearchItem" Visible="false" />`

IF that does not work, do the following...

Make a button with the same validation as the text box.
Set the height and width to the button to 0.
Set the border type to none
Set the background of the button to the background you are trying to place it on.
Boom, your button is hidden in plain sight and your validation group still works.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch123" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtSearch123_TextChanged" Width="217px" Text="Search for an item..." OnClick="this.value=''" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" ValidationGroup="SearchItem"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="" Width="0" Height="0" ValidationGroup="SearchItem" BackColor="#5F605F" BorderStyle="None" />
```

Comment: Can you show more surrounding code?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two concepts you need to understand first.

The fact is, that everything on a (normal) ASP.NET page is inside one single form. This also means that things like "pressing enter to send form" are a bit tricky, since they submit the whole form, which usually isn't what you want.

Now to the concepts:

- ValidationGroup - this setting on .NET validators (and buttons etc.) allows you to separate different logical forms inside the one superform. The validators will only evaluate if the originator of the submit action (eg. the "change password button") is in the same ValidationGroup. Properly configuring validation groups should make this part of your issue disappear.
- What happens on enter key press - by default, you send the whole form, without doing any button's action. So, if you have multiple logical forms on one page, you have to put each inside its own `Panel`, which has a `DefaultButton` property, which says "if I press enter inside this panel, it will act as if I clicked on this button".

Comment: Two or more controls must be associated with a validation group. In this case a button must be associated with my search bar, I do not want a button. Otherwise setting a ValidationGroup for my search bar does nothing.

Comment: @Waffles Well, one way would be to simply add a button with the required action, and hide it :)

Comment: Tried it. Using Visible="False" or even Enabled="False" does not work, just goes back to setting off validation of the ChangePassword control.

Comment: @Waffles Visible="False" actually completely removes the button from the page. Instead, you have to do something like `style="display: none;"`.

Comment: `btnSearch { display: none; }` does the same thing, causes validation of the change password control.

Comment: @Waffles Have you set the ValidationGroup to both btnSearch, txtSearch *and* the change password control?

Comment: I tried this initially, but then removed it when it didn't work. The following worked.
`<asp:ChangePassword ID="ChangePassword2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Password">
            </asp:ChangePassword>`

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch123" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtSearch123_TextChanged" Width="155px" Text="Search for an item..." OnClick="this.value=''" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" ValidationGroup="SearchItem"></asp:TextBox>`

`<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="" Width="0" Height="0" ValidationGroup="SearchItem" Visible="false" />`

Comment: Forgot to Ctrl+F5 and it no longer works, but I figured out a fix. See above for my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

SET **ValidationGroup** in your TextBox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch123" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtSearch123_TextChanged" Width="217px" Text="Search for an item..." OnClick="this.value=''" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" ValidaionGroup="Something"></asp:TextBox>
```

[Specifying Validation Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Two or more controls must be associated with a validation group. In this case a button must be associated with my search bar, I do not want a button. Otherwise setting a ValidationGroup for my search bar does nothing.